# Error in accessing protected member

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, package, protected

```
//Filename: A.java
package packageA;
public class A {
    protected int x;
}
```

---

```
//Filename B.java
package packageB;
import packageA.A;

public class B extends A {
    void action(A ob1, B ob2, C ob3) {
        x = 10;
        ob1.x = 10;   // <-- error here
        ob2.x = 10;
        ob3.x = 10;
    }

public class C extends B {
    void action(A ob1, B ob2, C ob3) {
        x = 10;
        ob1.x = 10;    // <-- error here
        ob2.x = 10;    // <-- error here
        ob3.x = 10;
    }
```

So, I was reading protected usage in Java and came across this problem. 
`A.java` and `B.java` are separate files and kept in separate packages as you can see. While compiling `B.java`, I get 3 ERRORS that `x` has protected access in `A`. Can somebody explain why I'm getting error even after extending class `A`?

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to access a protected member through the supertype reference. See [Java Language Specification, section 6.6.2: Details on Protected Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2).

> A compile-time error occurs in the method delta here: it cannot access the 
>   protected members x and y of its parameter p, because while Point3d (the 
>   class in which the references to fields x and y occur) is a subclass of 
>   Point (the class in which x and y are declared), it is not involved in the 
>   implementation of a Point (the type of the parameter p). The method 
>   delta3d can access the protected members of its parameter q, because the 
>   class Point3d is a subclass of Point and is involved in the implementation 
>   of a Point3d.

Answer (score 0):

In method `action` of class `B`, you get an instance of class `A` -- `ob1` as an argument.

The `ob1` itself is a pure class `A` object. It is not a instance of class `B` which extended from class `A`. So, you can't override protected member of class A outside of class A.

You can override a field member `x` of class B because the `x` is extended from class A's protected member `x`.

```
public class B extends A {

    // class B has member x in field which is extended from class A

    void action(A ob1, B ob2, C ob3) {
        x = 10;     // <-- this is extended field member x from class A in class B
        ob1.x = 10; // <-- this is protected member of other instance of A
        ob2.x = 10;
        ob3.x = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.